# React Hook From with Material UI Transfer List Component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I'm using the library react-hook-form with material-ui components.

I'm working on a form containing the customized component [Transfer List](https://v4-3-3.material-ui.com/components/transfer-list/); my goal is to access the content of the right hand side of the transfer list using the react-hook-form `register` or `Controller` constructs so when I call submit, I can get directly the left or right values as string list.

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the `Transfer list`, component form `material UI` left and right list values are stored in state variables. you can directly access them in the `submit` handler.

Comment: Please include your code, so that we will know exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, obviously, it depends on your form structure. I hope that it could be useful. I used the react-hook-form Controller and this is the code:

```
<Controller
 control={control}
 name="fieldName"
 render={({ field: { value }, fieldState: { error } }) => (
  <CustomTransferList control={control} error={error} left={left} right={value} />
 )}
/>;
```

and in the CustomTransferList I get the field with this command:

```
const { field } = useController({ name: "fieldName", control });
```

and then add the following code into the two functions to update the left and the right list:

```
const handleCheckedRight = () => {
 const updatedRight = right.concat(leftChecked);
 field.onChange(updatedRight);
}

const handleCheckedLeft = () => {
 const updatedRight = not(right, rightChecked);
 field.onChange(updatedRight);
}
```